# What is the wrong when i get the product attribute lable?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I am using two different ways to load the products in my magento page.

Method 1 : **Load the category products by Category id**

```
$productId = (int) trim($getId[0]);//HERE $productId IS A CATEGORY ID
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$_product = $obj->load($productId);

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_product ->getId());

$productslist = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');

foreach ($productslist as $_productslist) { $arrIds[] = $_productslist->getId(); }    

 //$arrIds[0] :- this variable holds the first product id of the collection.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($arrIds[0]);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes(); 
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) != "") {
        $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);
    }
}
```

In This way i can use `getStoreLabel` and retrieve the label values of the attribute for the product.

Method 2 : **Load the products by Product name**

```
$productName = (int) trim($_POST['partnumber']); //this is user search value for product name

$productslist = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('name', ['like' => $productName . '%']);

foreach ($productslist as $_productslist) { $arrIds[] = $_productslist->getId(); }
//$arrIds[0] :- this variable holds the first product id of the collection.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($arrIds[0]);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes(); 
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) != "") {
        $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);
    }
}
```

Here in method 2 a 404 page is coming.
What is the mistake i am doing here.I used the same way to get the attribute and attribute label for both scenario.

**UPDATE**

I managed to fix this issue by removing `$product` in `$label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);`, I want to know why this argument work in **method 1** and not work in **method 2**.Please explain me.

Comment: in your foreach you have used the same variable $productslist, if I am not wrong you just need a product name right ? or the store label please confirm

Comment: Thanks, i am using two methods with if condition.i need the product attribute labels only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to load whole collection if you just want the data of one product. please check the below code , hope this will help you.

```
$prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(5); // add your product id
$attributes = $prod->getAttributes();
$labels = array();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if (!is_null($attribute->getFrontendLabel())) { // you can get any value you want 
        array_push($labels, $attribute->getFrontendLabel());
// alternate code 

$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','attrbute_code'); // add attribute code here
array_pust($labels,$attributeModel->getStoreLabel('Store_id')); //add your store id.

    }
}
```

Sorry about the messy code :)